# Como fazer alteração de cor de uma row com um selected active do ngx-datatable?

Tags: css, angular, typescript, datatable

Boa tarde pessoal!

Já tentei de várias formas fazer uma alteração de mudança cor de uma row do ngx-datatable, mas única forma que consegui foi alterar o color hover da minha row. 
O que preciso é alterar a cor ao selecionar uma linha, igual a este exemplo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gk6hut?file=src%2Fstyles.scss, mas não consegui de nenhuma forma.

Como está atual:

```
:host
::ng-deep
.ngx-datatable.bootstrap:not(.cell-selection)
.datatable-body-row:hover,
:host
::ng-deep
.ngx-datatable.material:not(.cell-selection)
.datatable-body-row:hover
.datatable-row-group {
background: blue;
}
```

Comment: Não seria uma `,` faltando depois do segundo `.datatable-body-row:hover` http://prntscr.com/o0lbl4

Comment: Hugo, do jeito que está o código está funcionando, porém, está mudando somente a linha quando mantenho o mouse em cima da linha, que seria o *datatable-body-row:hover*, quando tiro o mouse, a cor do background volta. O que preciso é alterar a cor ao clicar, com um selected active que o próprio ngx-datatable possui, mas infelizmente não estou conseguindo.

Answer (score -1):

Acredito que se você utilizar como abaixo, funcione:

```
:host ::ng-deep .ngx-datatable.material.single-selection .datatable-body-row.active .datatable-row-group {
   background: red !important;
}
```

Mas você precisa deixar o *view-encapsulation* do seu *componente* como padrão.

Todo estilo com `::ng-deep` fica global. Lembrando também que esse é um recurso *deprecated* pelo time do Angular: https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep. E a estilização do `ngx-datatable` é baseada em SCSS https://swimlane.gitbook.io/ngx-datatable/themeing

Comment: Desculpe a minha ignorância patrick, mas estou começando no angular agora, como deixo meu view-encapsulation como default?

Comment: Somente não setando ele no `decorator` do seu componente. Por exemplo, tem que ficar somente assim: `@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})`, sem a propriedade `encapsulation:`

Comment: Muito obrigado, mas infelizmente não funcionou, já tentei de várias formas, mas o único atributo que consigo alterar é o row: hover mesmo.